# Why did God tell Moses to demand from Pharaoh that the Israelites leave for only three days?

Tags: parashas-shemos, sheker-false

God told Moses to demand from Pharaoh that the Israelites be able to leave Egypt for three days to worship God (Exodus 3:18). Why didn't God tell Moses to demand from Pharaoh that the Hebrews be freed forever? Is there any significance to this deceit?